# Using or in an if not statement

Tags: python

New to programming: I am trying to clean a file so that I just have a list of names on each new line.

I am currently stuck trying to figure out how to go through a text file and delete all lines that do not begin with an English letter.

```
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace = True):
        # Remove digits
        result = re.sub(r'\.{2,}', '', result)
        # Remove hyphens
        result = result.replace('-', ' ')
        # Replace unnecessary commas
        result = result.replace(' , ', '  ')
        result = result.replace(' ,', ' ')    
        result = result.replace(',  ', ' ')
        if not result.startswith(',') or result.startswith(' '):
            print(result)
```

This results in everything executed as intended except for the last if not statement. The new text file still has lines that start with spaces but does not print the lines that start with commas. How do I fix this if not statement?

Comment: You likely need a set of parentheses `if not (result.startswith(',') or result.startswith(' ')):`

Comment: Should the last `if` ask *does the line start with neither a comma or a space* or *does the line not begin with a comma or does it begin with a space*?

Comment: In English we can say "not this or that", and understand that _not_ applies to both _this_ and _that_, but Python doesn't work that way.  In your statement, _not_ is only applied to the first condition.

Comment: You only need a single call to `startswith`: `if not result.startswith((',', ' ')):`

Answer (score 0):

The condition `not result.startswith(',') or result.startswith(' ')`
means "does NOT start with comma" OR "starts with a space"

What you want is `not result.startswith(',') and not result.startswith(' ')` i.e. "does NOT start with comma" AND "does NOT start with a space"

Another option would be `not (result.startswith(',') or result.startswith(' '))`.
Thanks to the parentheses the "NOT" applies to the whole condition `(result.startswith(',') or result.startswith(' '))`

In logic, **not** (A **or** B) is the same as (**not** A) **and** (**not** B)